# How to use set_value on an uninitialized column with different datatypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering about the following behavior of `set_value`. Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=list("ABC"))

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [A, B, C]
```

When I now add values to it, e.g.

```
df.set_value('A', 'col_1', np.nan)
df.set_value('B', 'col_1', 10)
```

it works fine, however, it crashes when I add a string

```
df.set_value('C', 'col_1', 'test')
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: test

However, the same works perfectly fine when I use `.loc`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=list("ABC"))
df2.loc['A', 'c1'] = np.nan
df2.loc['B', 'c1'] = 10
df2.loc['C', 'c1'] = 'test'
```

and when I use `set_value` with an initialized column (here: `c_1`):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=list("ABC"), columns=['c_1'])
df3.set_value('A', 'c_1', np.nan)
df3.set_value('B', 'c_1', 10)
df3.set_value('C', 'c_1', 'test')
```

Why does the first approach fail while the others work? What would be the easiest way to make the first approach work?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Because any of these options will be horrifically slow if your data is even moderately large.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I just found it by coincidence. Speed is not an issue, it is just general interest why these things behave differently.

Comment: Why would they make two different APIs that worked exactly alike?  There is nothing interesting about this.